# how to use the functions of tmap :sum and count

Tags: talend

I use the `tMap` component to create the measurements of the fact table!
How I could create the measurements by using the sum for the total amount and the count of an account count for example.

I try this but i doesn 't work:

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you add more details on what you are trying to achieve. can you also add screenshot details about calculations you have put in tmap output

Comment: FYI : You should let your database do that join. Talend can do it, but a DB will do it much faster with the correct index.

Answer (score 0):

tMap component doesn't work for aggregate function.
Please use tArregateRow for such requirements